# The head of the model will have some parts transparent and the alpha is up to 1 in render only, this happens on render only, while in viewport doesn't

Tags: rendering

[image: Here's the problem]

In the viewport is normal, but when I render it, the head of the model will have some parts transparent and the alpha is up to 1

[image: Viewport]

Comment: In the Material settings, is the Blend Mode set to Opaque? Maybe pack your image and share your file?